# Inner Transaction not getting rolled back when their is Error in Outer trsansaction

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, transactions

I'm implementing a transaction in Spring boot. And we have a method startTransfer in which we have some business logic regarding checking the transaction and after that, the transaction is saved into the database using a DAO method. After saving it to the database we check the messageing queue server is working or not. If the server is not working we rollback the whole startTransfer Method and the database is rolled back.

Here is the startTransfer method

```
private static final MessageService messageService = new MessageService();

@Transactional(isolation = Isolation.READ_COMMITTED, propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW, readOnly = false, timeout = 500, rollbackFor = Exception.class)
public void startTransfer(String receiverID, String amount, String label, String senderID) throws QueueDownException {
    
    // some business logic, in which we are checking the senders balance and creating an object of the txn class 

    dbTxnDao.saveTransaction(txn);   // txn is getting saved and not rollbacked on QueueServerException 

    if(!messageService.checkWorking()) {
        throw new QueueDownException("Kafka Queue not working in the startTransfer");
    }
}
```

checkWorking() is another method which returns true when it's working else false.
this is the Dao

```
@Repository
@Transactional
public class DbTxnDAO {
    SessionFactory sessionFactory = new Configuration()
            .configure("hibernate.cfg.xml")
            .addAnnotatedClass(DbTxn.class)
            .buildSessionFactory();
    
    // method not getting rolled back
    @Transactional(isolation = Isolation.READ_COMMITTED, propagation = Propagation.MANDATORY, readOnly = false, timeout = 500,  rollbackFor = Exception.class)
    public void saveTransaction(DbTxn txn) {
        Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        session.beginTransaction();
        session.save(txn);
        session.getTransaction().commit();
        session.close();
        return;
    }

}
```

So when the checkWorking() method returns false and we enter the if block, the QueueDownException is thrown and the whole transaction must be rollbacked. But instead the dbTxnDao.saveTransaction(txn) is not rolled back.

How do I achieve the rollback of saveTransaction

Comment: Any reason why you need to manage Hibernate Session yourself?

Comment: Actually all the Dao, Dto entity have already been developed by other programmer

Comment: The thing is that you are mixing Spring Transaction Management (`@Transaction` annotation) with programmatic Transaction Management handled by you inside a code annotated with `@Transaction`. My first approach would be to get rid of the programmatic Transaction Management if you don't have a good reason to keep it.